# How to auto run demeteorized application on Windows

Tags: node.js, meteor, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008

I have a meteor application that I have demeteorized and deployed onto a windows server 2008 machine running node.

What I currently do to run the application is sign in to remote desktop and run a batch file which sets environment variables and calls node main.js. This starts the server, hosts the app and I simply close the remote desktop.

Clearly, this isn't ideal, if the server restarts I have to do it all over, also my account has to remain logged in with the command window open.

I have looked into foreverjs and played with task scheduling in windows but can't seem to find a good solution. My thoughts are a task that is run by a system account to set up the environment variables then calls forever on the application but can't seem to rig anything together that works without me signing in manually on restart.

Has anyone run into this situation and have suggestions for the best approach I should be taking?

Thanks

Comment: The simple solution I've used is to have windows autologin and stuck a shortcut to the batch file in the startup folder 

Comment: Autologin on a server, you must be kidding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run a meteor app under nginx and Phusion Passenger on Windows.

nginx is like Apache or IIS and will run as a service. Phusion Passenger is a plugin for nginx, so doesn't need to be run separately.

With this setup, you probably don't even need to de-meteorize your app

Comment: This doesn't solve the need to autostart the app itself. Meteorized or not, it needs to start on startup

Comment: It does solve that problem, because that's what Phusion Passenger does. nginx does the listening on the external port, and routes it to the meteor instance

Comment: I appreciate that

Comment: awesome, I'll give this a try